# How to lock item in Azure storage table to allow only one Azure function to access its data at a time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-queues

I added a lock flag in an Azure storage table hoping only one Azure function gets access to its data at a time. Below is how I did it:

Azure storage table with an item:

```json
{
   partitionKey: 'foo_id'
   foo: 'foo_data'
   bar: 'bar_data'
   isLocked: false 
}
```

And then I have queue triggered function that process and update foo/bar data in the table only if the item is not locked (isLocked == false).
The queue triggered function goes like this:

```py
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage):
    is_locked = get_property_from_table('foo_id', 'isLocked')
    if not is_locked:
        lock_task_in_table('foo_id') #isLocked = true

        #continue with business logics 
        #that retrieve/update foo&bar data in task

        unlock_task_in_table('foo_id') #isLocked = false
    else:
        #do nothing
```

However, when several messages concurrently tigger functions, it can still happen that more than two functions get table item data and run the business logic code at the same time. Is there any way I can allow only one Azure function to access my Azure table item at a time?

Answer (score 2):

•   You can do so by leasing the Azure blob storage along with the table storage. You can use this technique to ensure that only one azure function accesses the table partition at a given point of time and the update on data is consistent across the tables. For this purpose, create a blob and a table entry as follows and give the blob a name that matches up with the key to your table entity: -

[image: Table creation]

Following is the code for lease protected table access: -

[image: Lease acquire]

•   Thus, as you can see above, the try block code is accessing the entities in the table storage and updating it but since we have named the blob container with the reference of key of the table entity, we acquire a lease on that table entity by gaining a lease on that blob (named key of the table). Also, as we are giving the lease ID of the lease time period, which is definite, the table entity access will be locked by the function for that time duration. The output of the above code in the storage account workspace will be a blob name that matches the partition key of the table entity and an entry in the table storage in the entities table.

Thus, in this way, you can create a lock through this lease function on certain table entries. For more information, please refer the below link: -

https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/acquiring-locks-on-table-storage/